# format date and add or subtract number of days in date coming from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am using mysql and and php , currently i have date and time in my database but when i get the date using sql , i keep on getting 1970-01-01 no matter what date , but if i try to add still no luck ! can any one guide me

```
 $startDate = $result['startDate'];
 $date=date('Y-m-d',$startDate);
 echo $date;
```

it should be something like 01-07-2011 . but it dosn't i have tried strtotime() also . but it dosnt help . can any one help me .

```
 $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($startDate)) . " +1 day");
 echo $date;
```

answer should be 2011-07-02 but its 1970-01-02

thanks in advance

Comment: What does `echo $result['startDate'];` give?

Comment: you can add and subtract days [using mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), which might be easier/quicker

Comment: It would help if we knew for certain that the value of `$startDate` was something other than the UNIX epoch. Are you sure that you're actually getting what you assume you're getting from MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $result['startDate'] is a date type column, and you're on a version of php greater than 5.0.2, you're looking for:

```
 $startDate = $result['startDate'];
 $date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($startDate. ' +1 day'));
 echo $date;
```

Comment: Why not use `echo $result['startDate'];` if the column is of type `date` and therefore is in `Y-m-d` format anyway?

Comment: @Arjan, he wanted to add a day.

Comment: @Faizan: I had move the +1 day w/in the strtotime function. (try now)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL returns its dates as a 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' string by default. You're probably passing this string directly into `date()` in PHP, which is incorrect. date() expects a timestamp (seconds since Jan 1/1970). Since you're passing in an invalid date, it's going to default to timestamp 0, aka Jan 1970.

You can force MySQL to return a timestamp suitable for PHP usage with `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(yourdatefield)`. However, remember that MySQL is perfectly capable of doing date math within a query as well.

Answer (score 1):

If `startDate` is `datetime` type, and you want to use `date` function on php, you need to change your query to something like :

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(startDate) as startDate .....
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$result['startDate']` is a MySQL Date (or DateTime) then the following will work:

```
$startDate = $result['startDate'];
$date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day', $startDate));
echo $date;
```